# Can We Use Mutual Information to Determine if a Time Series has a Difference Trend or a Time Trend?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, trend, mutual-information, heuristic

Let's say we have a finite real-valued time series (finite subsequence of a realization of a real-valued stochastic process), $X_t$.

To address my question, we make no initial stationarity assumptions.

We plot the the time series and see that there looks to be some sort of trend, but we aren't sure what kind.

We then decide to try and make our time series approximately "more" stationary by detrending through use of a time trend or a difference trend.

In determining which to try to model, are there any blaring statistical problems with the following?:

Let $X_{t-k}$ denote a copy of $X_t$ lagged by $k$.

Also, let all mutual informations henceforth be assumed to be estimated by some form of K-Nearest-Neighbors such as [this](https://journals.aps.org/pre/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevE.69.066138) method

From our time series, we first estimate the mutual information between $t$ and $X_t$.

We then estimate the mutual information between $X_{t-1}$ and $X_t$.

From our time series, we then estimate the conditional mutual information between $t$ and $X_t$ given $X_{t-1}$.

We then estimate the conditional mutual information between $X_{t-1}$ and $X_t$ given $t$.

We then compare the magnitudes of the non-conditional mutual informations to see if one is much larger than the other or if either are significant in magnitude.

We then compare the magnitudes of the conditional mutual informations to see if one is zero or significantly less than the other, indicating approximate conditional dependence.

We then combine these comparisons to decide if our time series is best made "more" stationary by detrending with a time trend or a difference trend.

For example, say we find that the mutual information between $t$ and $X_t$ compared to $X_{t-1}$ and $X_t$ and that $X_{t-1}$ and $X_t$ appear to be conditionally independent (almost-zero/zero conditional mutual information) given $t$.

Is it correct to say that this would imply that we should choose to use a time trend over a difference trend?

I know that statistical guarantees surrounding correlations holding, etc. become muddled when we loosen the stationarity assumption, but is using an estimate of "universal" dependency valid here? I know that mutual information makes assumptions about the time-invariance of the distributions of the variables it's calculated on so what I'm doing may be theoretically incorrect, but are there any foreseeable problems I would run into by doing this to make modeling decisions?

Comment: Hi: Not an answer since I'm not familiar with conditional mutual information and it's connection to the issue.  One suggestion is to look at the nelson-plosser paper from the early 80's. They found that a number of well known series were difference stationary rather than trend stationary ( or I may have it backwards. it's been a while ) so maybe they had a method for doing that. This is the paper. https://hedibert.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/nelson-plosser-1982.pdf

Comment: By *difference trend* (which I hear for the first time), do you perhaps mean *stochastic trend* (result of a unit root)?

Comment: @mlofton thank you for the reference! I think I've seen this mentioned when looking into this subject. :)

Comment: @RichardHardy Yes, I think that by a "difference trend" I mean a stochastic (time?) trend. I've heard that as a more common name for what I mentioned, but was unsure on the terminology.

Comment: @QMath: Google for "difference stationary" or "trend stationary" or some combination of the two.  You should find a lot of results on that topic.